# From time to time calling Microsoft Azure hosted WCF service results in "trust relationship for the SSL/TLS" issues

Tags: azure, wcf, ssl, azure-web-app-service, tls1.2

From time to time calling Azure hosted WCF service results in "trust relationship for the SSL/TLS" issues while calling it through standard https://*.azurewebsites.net address. It was working good for many months. The problem started to appear several days ago without any changes in my code. Usually trying again is solving the problem and the operation is successfully completed.

I've tried several options in Azure Portal including changing the TLS version from 1.0 to 1.1 and 1.2, I've tried to use custom SSL secured domain, but the problem still appears.

The exact exception I have is:

> Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel with authority 'my-address.azurewebsites.net'. The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.SendAsyncResult.End(SendAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EndCall(String action, Object[] outs, IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.TaskCreator.<>c__DisplayClass7_0`1.<CreateGenericTask>b__0(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

Answer (score 0):

As you know, the error mainly indicates that the trust relationship isn’t established between the server and the client. The common way is installing the server certificate in local RootCA. You could download the certificate by using the browser address bar.
Alternatively, we could add the below code segments before calling the service in order to trust the server.

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += delegate
            {
                return true;
            };
```

Besides, the communication is established required that the OS version and Dotnet framework version support. Please refer to the below document.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls
We had better upgrade the application target framework/OS to support TLS1.2+.
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.